# Youtube player overlay listener

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I want to add sound notification when youtube player overlay appears.  Is it possible to detect when android youtube player overlay appears or dissapiears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not found a propper listener, so I listen to action bar insted.
If activity style hav property        `<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>` 
The actionBar will appear when overlay appear and dissapiear in save time. However It works only for fullscreen mode